# React native Firestore: Function addDoc() called with invalid data

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, svg, google-cloud-firestore

I try to upload an array of a bunch "paths" from a svg paintboard to firestore. But When I try do that I get following error:

> Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in document boards/document/userBoards/document)

Is it mean that my data is undefined?

```
     this.state = {
      results: [],
      color: Colors.color16,
      strokeWidth: 10,
      donePaths: [],
    };

    this._undo = this._undo.bind(this);
    this._setDonePaths = this._setDonePaths.bind(this);
  }

  _cancel = () => {
    this.setState({ donePaths: [] });
  }

  _undo = () => {
    this.setState({ donePaths: this.state.donePaths.slice(0, -1) });
  }


  _save = async () => {
    const result = await captureRef(this._signatureView, {
      result: 'base64',
      quality: 1,
      format: 'png',
    });

    const results = this.state.results;
    results.push(result);

    this.setState({ results });
  }

  _setDonePaths = (donePaths) => {
    this.setState({ donePaths });
    //if print donePaths here I get all the data.
    console.log(donePaths);
  }

  _changeColor = (color) => {
    this.setState({ color });
  }

    //Save the post with to current user using firebase
    _savePostData = (donePaths) => {
      console.log("my data" + donePaths);
      console.log("my user" + auth().currentUser.uid);
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('boards')
        .doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection("userBoards")
        .add({
          donePaths: [donePaths],
          creation: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        })
        .then(function () {
          props.navigation.push("Profile");
        });
    };
```

Here is my view:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header
          save={this._save}
          undo={this._undo}
          cancel={this._cancel}
        />

        <ColorSelector onPress={this._changeColor} />
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <SignatureView
            ref={(view) => { this._signatureView = view; }}
            donePaths={this.state.donePaths}
            setDonePaths={this._setDonePaths}
            containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFF', marginTop: 10 }}
            width={Dimensions.get('window').width - 20}
            height={Dimensions.get('window').width - 20}
            color={this.state.color}
            strokeWidth={this.state.strokeWidth}    
          />
        </View>

        <ResultImages images={this.state.results} />

        <Text style={styles.footer}>
        </Text>
        <Button
          title="Ladda Upp"
          onPress={() => this._savePostData()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it seems the data is undefined. Can you please `console.log(auth().currentUser.uid)` and `console.log(donePaths)` and share the output?

Comment: I get my user and but my data is undefined. If I upload an empty array it works fine.                                                                                                                     my data undefined                                                                                                           my user UW3PJASJQ3Rxmy2RobmQ6nGBv3c2

Comment: Then we'll have to look where the data is coming from and why it is undefined. Could you share some more code that deals with it?

Comment: Of course, I added some more code.

Comment: I doubt if the `savePostData` is being called before `_setDonePaths` and hence it is undefined? Also if the donePaths is an array you don't need to wrap it in `[]` again. `.add({ 
donePaths, creation: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() })` is sufficient.

Comment: I'am already call _setDonePaths before "savePostData", or I'am wrong? If  I just added the donePaths it says: can't find variable: donepaths.

Comment: Okay and that seems to be the issue. Where is `donePaths` defined? I can't see that in the given code.

Comment: I added some more code.